# PHP or Javascript - Find a specific string

Tags: javascript, php, regex

Finding a specific string is relatively easy, but I am not sure where to begin on this one. I would need to extract a string that would be different every time, but with similar characteristics.

Here are some example strings I need to find in a paragraph, either at the beginning, end or somewhere in the middle.

7b.9t.7iv.4x

4ir.4i.5i.6t

7ix.7t.4t.0z

As you can see the string will always begin with a number, and would have up to 2 characters after it and will always contain 4 octets separated by dots.

Let me know if you may need more details.

EDIT:

Thanks to the answer below I came up with this, while not pretty, does what I need.

```
$body="test 1f.9t.7iv.4x test 1a.9a.7ab.4xa test ";

$var=preg_match_all("([0-9][a-z]{1,2}\.[0-9][a-z]{1,2}\.[0-9][a-z]{1,2}\.[0-9][a-z]{1,2})",$body,$matches);

$count=count($matches[0]);
$stack = array();
while($count > 0){
  $count--;
  array_push($stack, "<span id='ip_".$matches[0][$count]."'>".$matches[0][$count]."</span>");
}
$stack=array_reverse($stack);
$body=str_replace($matches[0],$stack,$body);
```

Comment: Keyword: Regular Expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regular expression.

Something like this to get you started.  There may be a better way to match since it's repeated, but....

`([0-9][a-z]{1,2}\.[0-9][a-z]{1,2}\.[0-9][a-z]{1,2}\.[0-9][a-z]{1,2})`

`(` Start a capture group

`[0-9]` match any character 0 through 9

`[a-z]` match any character [a-z]

`{1,2}` but only match the previous 1 or 2 times

`\.` match a literal `.`  the `\` is needed as an escape because `.` is a special character

`)` End capture group

Both php and javascript allow for regular expression use.

For an even better visual representation you can check out this tool: http://www.debuggex.com/

If you need each octet by itself (as a match) you can add more parenthesis `()`  around each `[0-9][a-z]{1,2}` which will then store those octets individually.

Also note that `\d` is the same as `[0-9]` but I prefer the later as I find it a little more readable.